# Struts2 get object attribute from select tag

Tags: list, object, select, struts2

My problem is that I don't succeed in getting the attribute of the object of the list of my select tag.

I have a select tag in my .jsp like this :

```
<s:select list="listFonction" listKey="code" listValue="Libelle"
                name="fonctionSelectionne" value="defaultFonction" />
```

and in my action, i declared an arraylist (with getter and setter) :

```
private ArrayList<Fonction> listFonction = new ArrayList<Fonction>();
```

I also have another class Fonction :

```
public class Fonction {
    private int code;
    private String libelle;

    public Fonction(int code, String libelle)
    {
        this.code = code;
        this.libelle =libelle;
    }
    public Fonction()
    {

    }
    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getLibelle() {
        return libelle;
    }

    public void setLibelle(String libelle) {
        this.libelle = libelle;
    }
}
```

To get the selected value in my action i declared (whith getter and setter):

```
Private String fonctionSelectionne;
```

but i am just abbled to get the code (`listkey`) of my object with `getFonctionSelectionne`. 
I want to get the code attribute (`listkey`) and the `libelle` attribute (`listvalue`).

Does anyone know how help me ?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

2 points:

1. it should be **libelle**, not **Libelle**

   ```
   <s:select list="listFonction" listKey="code" listValue="libelle"
               name="fonctionSelectionne" value="defaultFonction" />
   ```
2. for list="listFunction", you need getter **Collection getListFunction(){}** in your action class

**UPDATE**

i'am not sure to this. but you can give a try.

here is the idea, don't deliver a list, but a map to select tag

```
Map getListFunction(){
Map<Object, String> map;
Function f = new Function(1, "test");
map.put(f, f.libelle);
return map;
}
```

then in the jsp:

```
<s:select list="listFonction" listKey="key" listValue="value"
            name="fonctionSelectionne"/>
```

Comment: point 1 : it Ok (just a mistake when I write out)
point 2 : I already have a getter for listFunction

Comment: did you put data in your `ArrayList<Function>`, you should rewrite the getter to get data for the select tag. like `getListFunction(){listFunction.add(new FUnction(1,"test"));return listFunction;}`

Comment: There are values in my list. Theses values are correclty displayed in the select but the problem is just when I try get the selected value. I get the key but I can't get the key and the value.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the setter of the attribute listFonction on the ClassAction